# RegExp does not return the expected result for parsing version number strings

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have file names like

```
TACO - v3 - something
BURRITO - v4.3
Enchilada - v5.1 - something
```

And I want to parse out those sweet versions (v5.1).

```
    var regExp = new RegExp("- (v.\S*)");
    var version = regExp.exec(fileName)[1];
```

But that only returns the first \S (so I get v5 rather than v5.1). I read somewhere else that google apps script regex doesn't do * or +, which seems crazy and it seems like lots of other people ARE using * and it works for them. What am I doing wrong?

Reiteration, I need the full version number (2 or 4 characters) regardless of whether anything follows it in the file name.

```
var regExp = new RegExp('- (v.\S*)\s*');
```

also works in my regex tester but not in GAS.  Expected result v5.1, actual result v5

Comment: Try double escapeing the `\S` and I think you can omit the dot `var regExp = new RegExp('- (v\\S*)');`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't escape the `.` in your regex with `\.`, it becomes a special wildcard that matches any character. Using the pattern `/v\d+(\.\d+)?/`, you can match a literal `v` followed by one or more digits, followed by an optional literal `.` and another run of digits. You may wish to make this group match zero or more times with the `*` quantifier if you have versions such as `v5.6.2`.

```js
const data = `TACO - v3 - something
BURRITO - v4.3
Enchilada - v5.1 - something`;

const result = data.match(/v\d+(\.\d+)*/g);
console.log(result);
```